# Query to retain tuples which were not subtracted

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two tables as follows

table1

```
name number
a    100
b    150
c    200
```

table 2

```
name number
a    10
b    20
```

How can I write a query to subtract both tables and retain values such as `c`

Output should be:

```
name number
a     90
b     130
c     200
```

I know how to get `a` and `b` just couldn't figure out how to keep `c` as well.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5f93/1/0)

```
SELECT
    t1.name as name,
    numer = t1.number - COALESCE(t2.number, 0)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name
```

Comment: i tried it and it gives my zeros for answers it is not subtracting the contents of the second table, i want all tuples from table to subtract tuples from table 2 but if there is no match for tuples then the value should be retained

Comment: Try to replace numer = t1.number - COALESCE(t2.number, 0) with (t1.number - COALESCE(t2.number, 0)) as number

Comment: I just tried what u gave and it did not seem to work